# How to validate a redux form field that has been formatted with commas

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-form

I have a field that must have a minimum value of 100,000 which is validated using a minValue function. The figure in the field must be formatted to display with commas where necessary, e.g - '100,000'

**Redux Field**

```
const minSumValue = 100000;

<Field
  name="buildings_sum_insured"
  type="text"
  format={formatNumberField}
  placeholder="Minimum €100,000"
  component={dgInput}
  validate={minValue(`${minSumValue}`)}
/>
```

**formatNumberField function**

```
function formatNumberField(number) {
  if (!number) return "";
   const n = parseInt(number.replace(/\D/g, ""), 10);
   return n.toLocaleString();
}
```

**Validate function**

```
export const minValue = min => value => value && value < min ? `Must be at least ${min}` : undefined
```

The format number function is working as expected, however it's causing the validate function not to work. The validation is functional without the format function present.

How can I validate the formatted number in the validate function? Do I need to parse the value and remove any special characters?

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does seem kind of silly to go from string to number to string to number again, so there might be some better way to do this.  But the following should work.  You could change the `minValue` function but instead I am leaving that untouched and converting the value to a `number` before we call it.

We remove all commas from the `string` and return its numeric value:

```
const toNumber = (value, fallback = undefined) => {
  return value ? parseFloat(value.replaceAll(",", "")) : fallback;
}
```

We use an arrow function to access the string `value` and then call the `minValue` function with its numeric conversion:

```
<Field
  ...
  validate={(value) => minValue(minSumValue)(toNumber(value, undefined))}
/>
```